# Como pasar una variable de string a double en Swift 2.

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode

Hola necesito pasar un **String** a **Double**, en este caso el dato lo pasare de un ViewController a otro mediante a **prepareForSegue** y el **Double** lo usare para centrar un mapa en la posición que le entregó por variable.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "Mapa_Rucapillan" {
        var nextScene = segue.destinationViewController as! mapController
            nextScene.ResivedLat = "100.0"
            nextScene.ResivedLong = "40.0"
    }
```

Ahi envío los datos.

```
var ResivedLat: String = ""
var ResivedLong: String = ""
```

ahí se reciben y esas las quiero pasar a Double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es muy simple

```
let string = "3.0"
let double = Double(string)
```

Este método devuelve un `Optional` por lo que en caso de que la conversión sea fallida, te devolverá `nil`

Answer (score 1):

En Swift 2 puedes usar [Double()](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html) :

```
Double("3.141592")
```

Si el valor no es numerico,

```
Double("no_es_numerico")
```

Obtendrias `nil`